# How do I map a JsonNode to an ArrayList of Object

Tags: java, jackson

**I have an input JSON Node as following**

```
"headers" : {
    "name1" : "value1",
    "name2" : "value2"
}
```

**My Java class looks as follows :**

```
    public class OptionalHeader{
        private String name;
        private String value;
        public OptionalHeader() {
            super();
        }
        public OptionalHeader(String name, String value) {
            this.name = name;
            this.value = value;
        }
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
        public String getValue() {
            return value;
        }
        public void setValue(String value) {
            this.value = value;
        }
    }
```

**I want to create an arrayList of OptionalHeader like below from the JsonNode.**

```
    List<OptionalHeader> optionalHeaders = new ArrayList<OptionalHeader>();
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: That is incomplete JSON. Please post the full thing.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all the replies :)

I required the JsonNode coming via REST request containing `key->value` pairs to be converted into an `ArrayList<OptionalHeader>`, see the `OptionalHeader` class in question.

finally did it using following:

(getting it as JsonNode in my POJO) coming via REST request. I used below in my setter.

```
public void setOptHeaders(JsonNode optHeaders) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
    this.optHeaders = optHeaders;
    List<OptionalHeader> allHeaders = new ArrayList<OptionalHeader>();
    Iterator<Entry<String, JsonNode>> nodeIterator = optHeaders.fields();
    while (nodeIterator.hasNext()) {
       Map.Entry<String, JsonNode> entry = (Map.Entry<String, JsonNode>) nodeIterator.next();
       OptionalHeader header = new OptionalHeader(entry.getKey(),entry.getValue().asText());
       allHeaders.add(header);

    }
    optionalEmailHeaders.addAll(allHeaders);
}
```

then following in the getter to convert it back.

```
public JsonNode getOptHeaders() {
    final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    final Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    for (final OptionalHeader data: optionalEmailHeaders)
        map.put(data.getName(), data.getValue());
    optHeaders = mapper.valueToTree(map);
    return optHeaders;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Jackson** mapper is there which can map Java Objects from/to JSON objects.
You can get the Jackson API from [here](http://jackson.codehaus.org/). 
Try saving your JSON string into a file eg. 'headers.json'.
Jackson provides a `ObjectMapper` class and you can use its `readValue( File file, Class class)` method to get the Java object from JSON like :-

`ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
OptionalHeader optHeader= mapper.readValue(new File("c:\\headers.json"), OptionalHeader .class);`

You can use the same link for getting the docs & read more about it.